# Can Testopia be installed with Bugzilla 4.4.6 running on IIS server

Tags: iis-7, bugzilla

I want to install Testopia to track Test cases and test results to our Bugzilla instance. We are using Bugzilla 4.4.6 hosted using IIS on a windows server 2008. I have not been able to find any documentation regarding this install. I dont want to try doing it before i read some documentation in the fear of corrupting the Bugzilla install.

Does any one have any experience with something like this? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the Testopia install instructions. Testopia is just a Bugzilla extension. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Bugzilla/Testopia

Answer (score 0):

We are running Testopia successfully with Bugzilla 4.4.9. Mind you, we needed a few patches for newer Perl versions such as this one:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=931961